# how to use one dbContext interface or interface<T> for multiple context and add to service collection in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible use one interface for all dbcontext in enterprise app.I want create one interface and base context with partial and use this for all dbcontext.

```
  public interface IComBaseDbContext : IDisposable // ComDbContext,
{
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;

    void AddRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class;
    void RemoveRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class;

    EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;...}


 public partial class ComBaseDbContext:DbContext
{
    public ComBaseDbContext()
    {
    }

    public ComBaseDbContext(DbContextOptions<ComBaseDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

   
}


 public partial class ComBaseDbContext : IComBaseDbContext
{

    public void AddRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class
    {
        Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
    }

    public void RemoveRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class
    {
        Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
    }...
}
```

and use in :

```
 public partial class ComDbContext : ComBaseDbContext
{
    public ComDbContext()
    {
    }

    public ComDbContext(DbContextOptions<ComBaseDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
   
    public virtual DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }...}
```

and add ComDbContext to service :

```
services.AddScoped<IComBaseDbContext, ComDbContext1>();
services.AddScoped<IComBaseDbContext, ComDbContext2>();
```

when use this pattern ComDbContext2 replace to ComDbContext1 .

how to change code to use this.how to use interface .Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1 :

If you want to define the context for each DI in controllers, create a generic interface:

```cs
public interface IComBaseDbContext<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
}
```

Implement custom generic context:

```cs
public class ComDbContext<TCotnext> : IComBaseDbContext<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TContext _context;

    public ComDbContextA(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new NotImplementedException(nameof(context));
    }

    public void AddRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Register in startup:

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IComBaseDbContext<>), typeof(ComDbContext<>));
```

Use in controllers:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IComBaseDbContext<AppContextA> _contextA;

    public HomeController(IComBaseDbContext<AppContextA> contextA)
    {
        _contextA = contextA;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _context.AddRange<..>(...);
    }
}
```

#### Option 2 :

If you want to have a common default context, and optionally change it in some controllers, create one generic and one standard interface.

```cs
public interface IComBaseDbContext<TContext> : IComBaseDbContext
    where TContext : DbContext
{
}


public interface IComBaseDbContext
{
    // ...
}
```

Then register in startup:

```cs
// This will use the default AppContextA
service.AddScoped<IComBaseDbContext, ComDbContext<AppContextA>>();

// This can have a generic AppContext
service.AddScoped(typeof(IComBaseDbContext<>), typeof(ComDbContext<>));
```

Use default context in controllers:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IComBaseDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(IComBaseDbContext context)
    {
        _contextA = contextA;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _context.AddRange<..>(...);
    }
}
```

Use a genric context:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IComBaseDbContext<AppContextB> _contextB;

    public HomeController(IComBaseDbContext<AppContextB> contextB)
    {
        _contextB = contextB;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _context.AddRange<..>(...);
    }
}
```